# Пост сообщения в группу ВКонтакте

Tags: php, вконтакте

Имею такой код:

```
<?
require 'vkapi.class.php';

$api_id = 2910988; // Insert here id of your application
$secret_key = 'fmbOO8SLWg0H3NBekYFu'; // Insert here secret key of your application

$VK = new vkapi($api_id, $secret_key);

//$resp = $VK->api('getProfiles', array('uids'=>'1,6492'));
$resp = $VK->api('wall.post', array('owner_id'=>'17741251', 'message' => 'qweqweqwe'));

print_r($resp);
?>
<?php

/**
 * VKAPI class for vk.com social network
 *
 * @package server API methods
 * @link http://vk.com/developers.php
 * @autor Oleg Illarionov
 * @version 1.0
 */

class vkapi {
    var $api_secret;
    var $app_id;
    var $api_url;

    function vkapi($app_id, $api_secret, $api_url = 'api.vk.com/api.php') {
        $this->app_id = $app_id;
        $this->api_secret = $api_secret;
        if (!strstr($api_url, 'http://')) $api_url = 'http://'.$api_url;
        $this->api_url = $api_url;
    }

    function api($method,$params=false) {
        if (!$params) $params = array(); 
        $params['api_id'] = $this->app_id;
        $params['v'] = '3.0';
        $params['method'] = $method;
        $params['timestamp'] = time();
        $params['format'] = 'json';
        $params['random'] = rand(0,10000);
        ksort($params);
        $sig = '';
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
            $sig .= $k.'='.$v;
        }
        $sig .= $this->api_secret;
        $params['sig'] = md5($sig);
        $query = $this->api_url.'?'.$this->params($params);
        $res = file_get_contents($query);
        return json_decode($res, true);
    }

    function params($params) {
        $pice = array();
        foreach($params as $k=>$v) {
            $pice[] = $k.'='.urlencode($v);
        }
        return implode('&',$pice);
    }
}
?>
```

На выходе получаю:

```
Array ( [error] => Array ( [error_code] => 4 [error_msg] => Incorrect signature: Session can be expired, revoked by user or connected with different IP address [request_params] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [key] => api_id [value] => 2910988 ) [1] => Array ( [key] => format [value] => json ) [2] => Array ( [key] => message [value] => qweqweqwe ) [3] => Array ( [key] => method [value] => wall.post ) [4] => Array ( [key] => owner_id [value] => 17741251 ) [5] => Array ( [key] => random [value] => 7404 ) [6] => Array ( [key] => timestamp [value] => 1334772077 ) [7] => Array ( [key] => v [value] => 3.0 ) [8] => Array ( [key] => sig [value] => accf1d951e833d0093f9450395298b1f ) ) ) )
```

Метод wall.get отлично работает, а post почему-то упирается. Что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Incorrect signature: Session can be
> expired, revoked by user or connected
> with different IP address

Обычно такая ошибка возникает при неправильном составлении подписи, но тут добавлен IP адрес. У Вас случаем не циклом долгим идут посты? У Вконтакте существует блокиратор соединений, может за превышенный лимит тормозит.

Comment: Ну вот как есть я исходник скинул, это все.
$resp = $VK->api('wall.post', array('owner_id'=>'17741251', 'message' => 'qweqweqwe')
Вот запрос: как видите никаких циклов...

Comment: Попробуйте сами составить переменную $sig.

Answer (score 0):

`wall.post` это - клиентский метод, который предназначен для т.н. [standalone-приложений и веб-приложений с окном подтверждения](https://vk.com/dev/wall.post). Серверный вызов этого метода без участия клиента невозможен..